# Why can't I catch this EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb

Server: WildFly10
JPA with eclipseLink 2.6.3-M1
JavaEE7

I have the following EJB:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class HandleRollbackComponent {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HandleRollbackComponent.class);

    @EJB
    private Tws14WSBatchChRequestsFacade tws14wsBatchChRequestsFacade;

    public void doSomething() {
        // first off go and fetch an instance of tws14 from the db
        logger.debug("*************************************************");
        logger.debug("1. First off go and fetch an instance of tws14 from the db");

        String batchChReqId = "103";
        Tws14WSBatchChRequests tws14wsBatchChRequests = tws14wsBatchChRequestsFacade.find(new BigDecimal(batchChReqId));
        logger.debug("2. Found instance of tws14: " + tws14wsBatchChRequests);
        logger.debug("2.1 CARD PLASTIC          : " + tws14wsBatchChRequests.getCardPlastic());

        try {
            logger.debug("3. Now call a method that throws the EJBTrxnRollBackException....");
            doSomethingThatThrowsEJBTransactionRolledbackException(tws14wsBatchChRequests);

            logger.debug("---> This line should not be logged if exception was thrown....");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("5. Caught the exception....");
        } finally {

            logger.debug("6. Finally try and get a fresh instance from the db again...");
            tws14wsBatchChRequests = tws14wsBatchChRequestsFacade.find(new BigDecimal(batchChReqId));
            logger.debug("7. Was able to get instance from db: " + tws14wsBatchChRequests);

            logger.debug("8. Try and update the instance of tws again...");
            tws14wsBatchChRequestsFacade.edit(tws14wsBatchChRequests);
            logger.debug("9. Could update the instance without problems.....");

            logger.debug("10. Check the OrderCards value: " + tws14wsBatchChRequests.getOrderCards() );
        }

        logger.debug("11. Done...");

    }

    public void doSomethingThatThrowsEJBTransactionRolledbackException(Tws14WSBatchChRequests tws14wsBatchChRequests) {
        logger.debug("4. Set some invalid values on tws14 in an attempt to get exception thrown...");
        tws14wsBatchChRequests.setOrderCards("N");
        tws14wsBatchChRequests.setOrderCards("");
        tws14wsBatchChRequests.setCardPlastic(null);

        tws14wsBatchChRequestsFacade.edit(tws14wsBatchChRequests);
    }

}
```

When I call doSomething() this is what I see:

---

1. First off go and fetch an instance of tws14 from the db
2. Found instance of tws14: za.co.fnds.persistence.entities.Tws14WSBatchChRequests[ batchChRequestId=103 ]
   2.1 CARD PLASTIC          : NBCRFLI_PIN
3. Now call a method that throws the EJBTrxnRollBackException....
4. Set some invalid values on tws14 in an attempt to get exception thrown...

   **---> This line should not be logged if exception was thrown....**
5. Finally trying to get a fresh instance from the db again...
6. Was able to get instance from db: za.co.fnds.persistence.entities.Tws14WSBatchChRequests[ batchChRequestId=103 ]
7. Try and update the instance of tws again...
8. Could update the instance without problems.....
9. Check the OrderCards value:
10. Done...

My question is why is the program not going into the catch clause because my logs indicates that a javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException was thrown. Why is the bold log above still show? What am I missing? Is there a way I'm supposed to be handling this program structure in an EJB?

Answer (score 0):

To verify that the implementation is wrong is the method doSomethingThatThrowsEJBTransactionRolledbackException. You can explicitly throw the exception and see if the cath works.

```
public void doSomething() {
    try {
        doSomethingThatThrowsEJBTransactionRolledbackException(new Tws14WSBatchChRequests());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public void doSomethingThatThrowsEJBTransactionRolledbackException(Tws14WSBatchChRequests tws14wsBatchChRequests) {
    throw new EJBTransactionRolledbackException();
}
```

If the exception is catching, then your code is not throwing anything